# Modulo Operation for Odd & Even Number

Tags: python, modulo

I want to check the Even or Odd numbers therefore I have written the following code:

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

if number % 2 == 0:
    print("This is an even number")
else:
    print("This is an odd number")
```

It gives the following result:

> Which number do you want to check? 20 
> This is an even number

But when is change the above code inversely like this

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

if number % 2 == 0:
    print("This is an odd number")
else:
    print("This is an even number")
```

It gives the following result:

> Which number do you want to check? 20 
> This is an odd number

even if I change the "If modulo operation" to % 7 == 2 it would still give even as odd or vice versa

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if number % 2 == 0: print("This is an even number")
> else: print("This is an odd number")
> ```
>
> But when is change the above code inversely like this
>
> ```
> if number % 2 == 0: print("This is an odd number")
> else: print("This is an even number")
> ```

You only switched the print statements but you didn't update the if condition.

We know that if an integer mod 2 is 0, then it is even... or if an integer mod 2 is 1, then it is odd. So you should change the condition of the bottom piece of code to `if number % 2 != 0`